# DDL Trigger Oracle

Tags: oracle

I've created one audit table which will record information which object is created in the schema and by whom.

```
hr@SSC> create table create_audit
  2  ( created_Date date,
  3  object_type varchar2(30),
  4  object_name varchar2(30),
  5  created_by varchar2(20));
```

This is the trigger which I've created:

```
  1      create or replace trigger create_trg_audit
  2      after create on schema
  3      begin
  4      insert into create_audit values
  5     (sysdate, ora_dict_obj_typ, ora_dict_obj_name , ora_dict_obj_owner);
  6*  end create_trg_audit;
```

I'm receiving below error while creating this DDL trigger:

```
hr@SSC> show error
Errors for TRIGGER CREATE_TRG_AUDIT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/16     PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Can't we give insert command in DDL triggers?

```
hr@SSC> select object_type, object_name ,owner from all_objects where last_ddl_time > sysdate-10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo; your insert refers to `ora_dict_obj_typ` instead of the (valid) `ora_dict_obj_type`, so you're just missing the final `'e'`. The [event attribute functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS794) documentation lists the valid values, and also shows them being used in the `values()` clause of an `insert`.

With that event attribute function name corrected your create trigger statement works:

```
create or replace trigger create_trg_audit
after create on schema
begin
   insert into create_audit (created_date, object_type, object_name, created_by)
   values (sysdate, ora_dict_obj_type, ora_dict_obj_name, ora_dict_obj_owner);
end create_trg_audit;
/

Trigger CREATE_TRG_AUDIT compiled

show errors

No errors.
```

And does what you wanted:

```
create table t42 (id number);

Table T42 created.

select * from create_audit;

CREATED_DATE OBJECT_TYPE          OBJECT_NAME          CREATED_BY    
------------ -------------------- -------------------- ---------------
2016-04-20   TABLE                T42                  MYUSER
```

Answer (score 1):

The values you are trying to insert are undefined when used as part of the insert statement. Use a `insert..select` statement instead to pull them from `dual` as follows:

```
create or replace trigger create_trg_audit
after create on schema
begin 
insert into create_audit select sysdate, ora_dict_obj_type, ora_dict_obj_name, ora_dict_obj_owner from dual;
end create_trg_audit;
```

Comment: It work like a charm but I didn't understand this why they are undefined when used as part of the insert statement.

Comment: That isn't true; the `ora_dict_*` references are [event attribute functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS794), and `sysdate` is also a function. You can refer to any of them in a PL/SQL context or in the `values()` clause. What you've shown works of course but the `select from dual` isn't required.